# How to implement the history by weekly, monthly, yearly

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I wrote an system to record every trade,including amount,customer,date,...

but now I need to implement a function to show the history of recent 1 month, recent 3 month,...,

what's the best practice to implement on RoR

Should I create another table to record an monthly data, weekly data ?

or just re-calculate all the history, when the user do the select query ? But I thought it may has bad performance using this method.

Comment: Would depend on amount of records you have. With good indexing you can calculate on the run for a few thousand or maybe tens of thousand of records. Beyond that you will most likely do better with aggregation tables.

Comment: There is a time and a place for everything, including summary tables.  One of those might be worth your while in this case.  If you summarize by day, you will only need one table and will still get better performance than querying the raw data.

Comment: hi @thorstenmüller hi,is there any keywords to find the sort of information. because i can not understand what method I should take , thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your data is only ever inserted, then aggregation tables are pretty easy to manage. Deletions and updates get a bit trickier.

Don't forget that calendar weekly (ie. Mon-Sun) data doesn't aggregate to months.
One great advantage of maintaining summary tables is that you can effectively index on summary data, so finding all stocks with a monthly trade volume greater than a particular quantity becomes practically instantaneous, and if you have that kind of requirement then I'd definitely go down that route.

Comment: hi,is there any keywords to find the sort of information. because i can not understand what method I should take , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Better use act_as_versioned for history functionality.It's easy track the history of the record using act_as_versioned.